# Polynomial of Least Degree

Tags: polynomials

What is polynomial of the least degree? How is it different from a polynomial of any degree? Is it possible to give some examples? I came across this from the definition of minimal polynomial of a in a field.

Thanks

Comment: $x^4-4$ is a polynomial having root $\sqrt2$, but $x^2-2$ is a polynomial of least degree having root $\sqrt2$

Comment: I meant a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$; otherwise $x-\sqrt2$ would be a polynomial of least degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a polynomial of degree $d$ having whatever property is being discussed, where there do not exist polynomials having that property and degree less than $d$.